# How to output all the hierarchical clusters from a numpy linkage array?

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

The scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage function outputs the cluster tree but is there a function which outputs all the clusters in the hierarchical tree?

Answer (score 0):

There exist (up to) `2*n-1` clusters in hierarchical clustering.

Looking at all of them is not sensible.

Instead, understand what the dendrogram is, and how to *extract* a flat partitioning out of it as desired, e.g. using the [`fcluster`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster) function.

Comment: Yes definitely fcluster would be helpful here but do you have any specific suggestions when you do need to evaluate every single one of the exponentially many clusters?

Comment: 2*n is not exponentially many. I advise to *not* evaluate all of them, as this will be prone to overfitting and introduce data snooping bias. If you test too many clusters, one will score high *by chance*. This is not meaningful.

Comment: what do you mean by "evaluate all of them"?

Comment: "There exist (up to) 2*n-1 clusters in hierarchical clustering." there are never more than `n` clusters at once so this might be misleading. Further more the total number of clusters formed is *always* `2*n-1` cause there are always `n` singletons and `n-1` agglomerations.

Comment: @embert nope. If all points are identical, there exists only a single cluster even at height 0. And if I run single-link clustering of the integers 1 to n, I get n clusters at height 0, and 1 cluster at height 1; so n+1 clusters total. There is no good reason to merge them one-by-one when they have the exact same merge height.